# Keyboard shortcut to resize object in PowerPoint

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint

In Microsoft PowerPoint, if you run your mouse over the edge of an object the cursor changes to `Move`. Click the edge of the object and you can move it around the slide with any of the following:

- <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> (called arrow below)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + arrow
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + arrow

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+arrow keyboard shortcut is particularly useful because you can quickly move items around pixel-by-pixel to their most attractive location.

However, try as I might I cannot find a shortcut for `resize`. Some editors, such as Visual Studio, have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+arrow and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+arrow to accomplish these separate tasks. Is there anything like this in PowerPoint?

Using PowerPoint 2000 if relevant.

Comment: This is kind of old question. But to add a followup question, is there a keyboard shortcut to go to height or width size option, when you would like the set either of them manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> change the height of the shape.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> change the width of the shape.

If the shape's aspect ratio is locked, changing height will change width proportionally and vice versa.

This is in PowerPoint 2010. I haven't used 2000 in a long time, but I'm fairly sure the key combos should be the same.

**UPDATE**: I've checked this in PowerPoint 2000, 2002, 2003 and 2007 and found it doesn't work in any of them. Apparently this feature was introduced in 2010.

Comment: Hmm, was sure I had tried that key combination but will try again and report back. Thanks.

Comment: As it happens, I've got a copy of PPT 2000 in a VM and fired it up to check this out.  Unfortunately Ctl+Shift+Arrowkeys doesn't resize shapes. You can get to the Format | Size dialog using Shift+F10 then O then right-arrow, then Tab your way around the dialog box and enter the new size you want (but to size things visually, that's no help).

Comment: Good suggestion. Done.  Luckily, I've got a VM with Office 97 through 2007 installed.